Air-cooled diesel engine of 15 hp for car
Are air cooled single cylinder diesel engines of around 15 HP recommended to build basic (low technology) four-seater cars & light cargo vehicles?
If so, are there any detailed engine designs available online that we could explore?

what is a basic 4 seater car?

research Citroën 2CV

An engine like that would be suitable for a small farming/garden tractor, but it would be extremely unpleasant in a car.

Check out these manufacturers: Kubota, Kawasaki, Yanmar, Subaru/Robin, Briggs & Stratton. Single-cylinder diesels in that size are used to run pumps and to power small boats. They are noisy, and vibrate very badly.

Deutz has been making them forever. There are also a number of Chinese knock-offs. Anything that has emissions rating will cost more than a crate SBC though. Chinese something for \$400 US. Deutz tier IV three banger about $10,000 US (36kW - smallest they have).
Also, a while back just before Covid, I had three small Kubota diesels with high hours that needed a little work. I couldn't give then away. Then after the Covid supply problems, and with tier IV going into effect, You couldn't buy one at any price. You need to keep an eye on what stuff is available cheap if you are going bottom fishing.

No.  A 15 hp engine is insufficient to power any automobile made to modern safety standards and expected to run at the speed limit.
Here is a point of reference, the Honda Grom is a tiny motorcycle with a top speed of about 55 mph; it has a 10 hp engine.
